# Bootstrap file upload button not working within background-image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So since im new I cant show you guys any pictures to demonstrate the issues that im having, but ill try to explain it to you in the best way.

I have a background-image: url(), that works as my "hero" for my website, I also have a bootstrap button that i use as a "browse your pc for a file" button, but for some reason the button isnt clickable when inside my hero tag, only when i put it outside.

HTML

```
<body>

    <div id="hero">
        <div id="hero-overlay">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AppInvest</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analyze</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
                <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none;">
                Browse...
            </label>

            <div style="background:transparent !important" class="jumbotron text-center">
                <h1>
                    AppInvest
                </h1>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 text-left">
                            <p>Who are we?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#hero {
    background-image: url('../img/rarri.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -10;
}

#hero-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -5;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Also if you could give me some tips on the best way to make an upload button with a "total files attached" at the center of the screen i would appreciate it.

And yeah obviously its CSS and HTML related.

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I had to figure out how to post it, but there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button isn't clickable because of the negatvie `z-index` of `#hero`. the z-index has no effect anyway in this szenario so i removed it and it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/967h3ty2/

To have a "total files attached" at the center of the screen you need to count the uploaded files on the server side using php or a similar technology.

Comment: Don't forget to accept it as a right answer @Kingkong